# How to emit Tauri backend (rust) event from new thread spawn outside of Builder?

Tags: rust, events, emit, tauri

I have a rust code in tauri app which browse bonjour services using mdns-sd and when found should pass it to the frontend using tauri event system. The Tauri documentation explains how to emit event from inside the Builder function, but i have a loop running in separate thread spawn before the Builder runs:

```
...
fn main () {
   ...
   std::thread::spawn(move || {
        //browse for services here and need to pass it to frontend as found
   });
   
   tauri::Builder::default().setup...
...
}
```

I have tried to move spawning the thread inside the .setup of Builder, but the app property is anyway unavailable inside thread even when it's there.

Comment: When you moved the spawn call into the setup hook, did you also try moving an AppHandle into the thread or just the App from the setup hook?
You can get an AppHandle via app.handle() and that handle can be moved into threads just fine generally.